# Deployment Error (Urgent Please)

Tags: custom-object, deployment, error, eclipse, list-view

When I am trying to deploy **new** **custom objects** along with list views using eclipse from sandbox to Production.I am getting below error for all new custom objects

> This View Unique Name already exists or has been previously used.  Please choose a different name

Also looked into this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/74238/error-in-list-view-unique-name-when-deploying-to-new-org) and he also had similar issue with deployment of list view.I tried to  remove the tag what he has mentioned in the answer but still failing no luck.

Here is another salesforce help [link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000186612&language=en_US)

Any Idea why its failing or do I need to delete all the list views from custom objects.

If I need to delete list views please let me know the mass delete list views using eclipse

Comment: Just curious, why not use a change set?

Comment: @AdrianLarson There are like 15 new custom objects  and corresponding   new custom fields.So its easy if you do with eclipse rather doing it with change set

Comment: Based on this question, I beg to differ. Depending on the org of course some might see your solution as lower effort. If you had to delete all list views from all objects though that is not necessarily even an option.

Comment: I commonly get this error when some listview name's characters are suddenly capitalized (or lower case). Salesforce recognizes it as the same name, but tries to deploy it as a separate listview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the list views manually and then deploy the new custom objects to production.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to delete the existing view with the same name (not label). Or change the name of the view you are trying to deploy.

Comment: I don't have the  existing views with same name

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar problem.
I figured out this was being caused by a sharing rule in the list view. The object affected had some views with the following tag:

`< sharedTo>`

`< allInternalUsers></allInternalUsers>`

`< /sharedTo>`

Interestingly, I removed those views, and could make the deploy.

I believe this is caused by a legacy feature that Salesforce tries to migrate to the new org. I had similar issues with profile permissions (some permissions don't exist in the newer orgs, but still do in the old ones).

Answer (score 0):

If you get stuck in a situation like this again, there are third party tools that can help you track down what list views are in the target org that might be causing a conflict.

Full disclosure that I lead the team, but we are building https://gearset.com which makes this kind of insight and deployment easier than Change Sets or `ant` directly.